flutter_secure_storage for web get error: type LegacyJavaScriptObject is not a subtype of FutureOr<CryptoKey>
Error in chrome:
"TypeError: Instance of 'LegacyJavaScriptObject': type 'LegacyJavaScriptObject' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<CryptoKey>?'"
Code - from flutter_secure_storage that got the error:

flutter_secure_storage_web.dart:

      encryptionKey = await js_util.promiseToFuture<html.CryptoKey>(
        crypto.generateKey(algorithm, true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]),
      );

Code - in project that cause the error:
// save token & misc
Future<void> storeToken(data) async {
  const storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  // Write value
  await storage.write(key: keyToken, value: data["token"]);
  await storage.write(key: keyExp, value: data["exp"].toString());
  await storage.write(key: keyId, value: data["id"].toString());
  await storage.write(key: keyUsername, value: data["username"]);
  await storage.write(key: keyNick, value: data["nick"]);

  // get value (optional)
  var nick = await storage.read(key: keyNick);
  debugPrint("nick: $nick");
}

Versions

dart: 3.4.3
flutter: 3.22.2
flutter_secure_storage: flutter_secure_storage_web-1.2.1
chrome: Version 126.0.6478.126 (Official Build) (64-bit) on linux.

The code works yesterday, today when I open & debug, the error occur.

I tried to restart the debug many times, the error remained, but after I add a simple debugPrint() line, and restart again, the error is gone, not sure what's the problem.
